# Powershell returns null instead of an exception when accessing COM property that fails

Tags: powershell, exception, error-handling, null, com

I've got the following COM interface and COM object that is implementing this interface:

```
[
    object,
    uuid(8FF1207F-24DD-4F34-B6CB-D90904CF4094),
    dual
]
interface IThrowingProperty : IDispatch
{
    [id(1), propget]
    HRESULT IntPropertyValue([out, retval] int* pVal);
}

[
    uuid(3869048C-A14F-4536-9FFC-0A4ECAEF2B08)
]
coclass ThrowingProperty
{
    [default] interface IThrowingProperty;
};
```

This property is always returning an error:

```
STDMETHODIMP CThrowingProperty::get_IntPropertyValue(/*[out,retval]*/ int* pVal)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}
```

But when I try to access it in Powershell I am getting no error and property value is equal to $null:

```
$PropertyWillThrow = New-Object -ComObject "PowershellCom.ThrowingProperty"
$PropertyWillThrow.IntPropertyValue
$PropertyWillThrow.IntPropertyValue -eq $null
```

[image]

Is it possible to get an error from a COM property in Powershell without changing property to method?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Note that this solution is not specific to COM objects, but will work with any object type in PowerShell.

It won't throw an error, it will just return `$null`. This is normal behavior for PowerShell when accessing a non-existent property on an object. However, you can check if the property is truly defined on an object via the following code. Testing against the Excel COM Object:

```
 # Returns true if property exists
 $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
 [bool]( $excel.PSobject.Properties.Name -match 'EnableCheckFileExtensions' ) # ==> True
 [bool]( $excel.PSobject.Properties.Name -match 'NonExistentPropertyName' ) # ====> False
```

`EnableCheckFileExtensions` is a property on the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass` type, so it returns true, but `NonExistantPropertyName` does not exist, so the evaluation returns false.

---

If you want an error-driven behavior here, you could use [`Add-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member) to add a `ScriptMethod` to your COM Object on the PowerShell side to check that the property exists before accessing it. Using the previous Excel COM object as an example again:

```
$checkPropertyExistsBlock = {
  Param(
    [string]$memberName
  )

  if( [bool]( $This.PSobject.Properties.Name -match $memberName ) ) {
    $This.$memberName
  } else {
    throw "Property ${memberName} does not exist" 
  }
}
$excel | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name 'GetPropertyByName' -Value $checkPropertyExistsBlock

$excel.GetPropertyByName( 'EnableCheckFileExtensions' ) # ==> Returns property value
$excel.GetPropertyByName( 'NonExistentPropertyName' ) # ====> throws exception
```

Of course, if you control the class's source code yourself, you could also add `GetPropertyByName` as a method on your class, and use reflection to implement the same logic as the `ScriptBlock` above without having to modify the object in-flight after it's been initialized.